# How to combine all objects in an .fbx file into one object

Tags: .fbx

I have around 15k fbx files and the models in them are split into pieces. I want to have all of them contain only one object.

I have this:

[image]

And I want this:

[image]

Having a lot of files, I'm wondering if it is possible to do this for all of them automatically.

Comment: have you tried just joining them?  the shortcut is ctrl+J

Comment: Yeah, but there are 15000 files and i can't do them manually.

Comment: hm, that does pose a problem.  I'm not sure how to automatically join thousands of objects like that. There might be an addon that someone has made for this, but I don't think there's a really easy way around this.